# VS Code Windows 10: LaTeX Workshop will not compile

Tags: path, latex, visual-studio-code

On Windows 10, I have **MiKTex** (as admin) installed and updated. Within **VS Code**, I have installed the **LaTeX Workshop** extension, but my document will not compile. I require **lualatex**, so I have moved that "recipe" to the "first" position in LaTeX Workshop's `.json` file, but compiling throws the message `Recipe terminated with error`. Looking at the console shows `Undefined control sequence` with my document's file path `c:\Users\...etc...` -- this is relating to the first line of the document [1,1] where I have the typical `\documentclass[12pt]{article}`.

It seems that the extension isn't able to locate the Path to the LaTeX executables...does this sound right? It is almost like it is looking in my files own directory for the LaTeX classes and packages, etc. In my Windows System Environment Variables, the path to `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\` seems to be correctly configured. Oddly, if I try to compile using **pdflatex**, it does not seem to encounter this specific issue (rather showing the error that I need to use **lualatex**, which I am trying to do).

Has anyone had this issue, or knows a way to fix it?

Comment: `Undefined control sequence` sounds very much like an latex error messages, so the executable seems to be found. A [mre] and the `.log` file would be useful to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 2):

1: It might be some problem related to "pdftex vs pdflatex"... Now I have the same but looking for the solution... (Win10; VSCode + Latex Workshop extension; WSL2; TexLive 2020 on Ubuntu 20.04;)

2: I've found something... in: "latex-workshop.latex.tools"

```json
{
    "name": "pdflatex",
    "command": "pdftex", 
    "args": [
        "-synctex=1",
        "-interaction=nonstopmode",
        "-file-line-error",
        "%DOC%"
    ],
    "env": {}
},
```

I changed `"command": "pdftex"` to `"command": "pdflatex"`
Now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you got [TeX Live](https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-windows.exe) installed. The installation takes some time, but as you've installed it, it should work.

Comment: What's the point of installing texlive if the OP already has miktex installed?

Comment: Correct me if Im wrong, but as far as I know LaTeX Workshop supports only TeX Live.

Comment: What does any program care if latex is installed by miktex or texlive? The error message of the op indicates that the executable is found.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz no, it doesnt. Go ahead, install VSCode and LaTeX Workshop on a new system without TeX Live installed and try to compile it to pdf. You will get the exact same error message, it's reproducable. I know that, because I tried it. I dont know why, maybe the compiler is looking for a specific installation path from TeX Live.